# Error: Invalid field user for SObject User

Tags: email, html, user, new

I am trying to create a visualforce template for new users so we can generate  a welcome to the team email and outline key information.  I am having some trouble trying to save this as I kept getting the error message

> Error: Invalid field user for SObject User

Copy of code

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="User"
relatedToType="User"
subject="Welcome to Salesforce at Compac"

replyTo="phil.prior@compacsort.com">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody>

<html>

<style type="text/css">
        body {font-family: calibri; size: 11pt;}
        h1 {font-family: calibri; size: 15pt; foreground: Blue;}
</style>

<body>
<h1>Welcome to Compac</h1>

<p>Hi {!recipient.user},</p>

<p>Welcome to Compac.  As a new employee requiring access to Company data, 
you can now login to Salesforce using your standard network login. 
</p>

<p>Information about Salesforce at Compac and login instructions can be found on the 
Compac Wiki at https://wiki.compacsort.com/display/IT/About+Salesforce.   
</p>

<p>A quick option first time is to login to Office 365 <a href ="https://login.microsoftonline.com/"/> and you 
should see the Salesforce link under the My Apps link 
(click the top left icon to view My Apps).  You can also login using a 
work account from https://compacsort.my.salesforce.com.  Once you are in you 
can bookmark the page for future access.   
</p>

<p>Please note that you cannot login via the standard Salesforce website due
 to our company security requirements.  You always need to login via this 
 custom domain, including on mobile devices if you have access.  </p>

<p>Your Salesforce setup is as follows. </p>

<ul>
<li>Profile: {!User.Profile}</li>
<li>Salesforce1 Mobile: {!User.Salesforce1User}</li>
<li>Public Group: {!Public_Group__c.Name} </li>
<li>Data Access:   </li>
<li>Reporting Access:  </li>

</ul>
<p>With access to this data, there comes responsibility. Please be aware 
of confidentiality at all times when accessing, using or sharing this data.  </p>

<p>Training on Salesforce is available.  This may be via Skype, as a 
group session or one to one depending on timing. Please contact me to 
make arrangements for training suitable for your role.    </p>

<p>We hope you make full use of Salesforce to assist you in your role and look forward to working with you. </p>

<p>Kind Regards</p>
{!recipient.name}


</body>
</html>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be first line to me

Hi {!recipient.user},

The above is wrong and corrected below

> Hi {!recipient.name}

Comment: @iamjury If that answered please upvote and mark as answered !